# SharePoint WSS 3.0 Integration with Mac OSX (either Safari or Firefox)

Tags: sharepoint, macos, wss

We have a SharePoint WSS site and some of our users on on the Mac OSX platform.  Are there any tips or tricks to get a similar experience to Windows with document shares and calendars on the Mac?

Edit: Browsing a SharePoint WSS site on a Mac, whether using Firefox or Safari, has a very similar look and feel as it does on Windows IE.  The similar experience I am looking for has to do with integrating the calendars, document shares, etc. into the desktop.

For example, with IE you can go to a calendar and select "Actions -> Connect to Outlook" and it will make the calendar visible and manageable from within Outlook.

Is there any way to get the Mac to work similarly?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the "full" Sharepoint Experience is limited to running Internet Explorer 6/7 and Office 2007.

On the Mac, I recommend using Firefox (Camino?) which seems to work a bit better than Safari.

Edit: When you say "Similar experience", what exactly are you missing? I don't have any Mac here, but I was under the impression that Office 2008 will have a working integration with Sharepoint as well.

Answer (score 1):

Office 2008 allows limited connectivity to MOSS. However there is no Mac OS browser yet that is completely compatible to MOSS.

I do have it on good authority the Microsoft Mac BU team is working with the MOSS team to see this changing in future versions of the platform, specifically around the Safari support.

Answer (score 0):

ActiveX is used to enable the bridge between MOSS and Office, and as ActiveX is only on Windows, you will find that you cannot get the full experience if you do not use Windows as your OS.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Sharepoint looks to client installs of Office applications and Active X in order to fully integrate.